# How to replace old value with new value in template using python?

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

i need to change old value to new value in template file.

Actually, when user enter 10 digits mobile number python function will call. if i check in log it's showing value but in html file it's  not showing value. how to get that value in second time calling function in views.py?

> views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import json
@csrf_exempt
def default(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        print("inside the ajax")
        phone_no = request.POST.get('phone_no')
        print(phone_no)
        dict = {'phone_no': phone_no}
        template_name = 'mobile_recharge.html'
        extended_template = 'base.html'
        dummy_var = 'test'
        print(dummy_var)
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            extended_template = 'base_login.html'
        return render(request,template_name, {'extended_template': extended_template,'phone_no': phone_no,'dummy_var': dummy_var})
template_name = 'mobile_recharge.html'
extended_template = 'base.html'
dummy_var = 'test'
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    extended_template = 'base_login.html'
return render(
    request, template_name,
    {'extended_template': extended_template,'dummy_var': dummy_var}
)
```

> script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#phone_number').on('input', function () {
        if ($(this).val().length >= 10) {
            alert("user enter 10 digits numbers");
            var phone_no = $('#phone_number').val()
            console.log(phone_no);
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "http://localhost:8090/",
              data: {'phone_no' : phone_no},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(msg)
              {
                   //alert(msg.phone_no);
              }
           });
            return;
        }
     });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
{{phone_no}} {{ dict }} {{dummy_var}}
```

If i call above variables in templates. i didn't get any result. How to get result?

Comment: Can you please read your question again and correct it?

Comment: From what I understand of what you're trying to do, I would say, either reload the page or update the phone_no with your javascript. There's currently nowhere where you update it.

Comment: i want to pass dummy_var result to html file. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
import json
@csrf_exempt
def default(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.user.is_authenticated() and 'phone_no' in request.POST:
        phone_no = request.POST['phone_no']
        dummy_var = 'test'
        dict = {'phone_no': phone_no}

        context = {'phone_no': phone_no, 'dict': dict, 'dummy_var ': dummy_var}
        return render(request, 'mobile_recharge.html', context)
    else:
        HttpResponseForbidden()
```

If you really need to print variables, use logging instead.

Comment: still i didn't get any value in html file. it's not first time when user enter 10 digits mobile number ajax function will call python function. python function will not send result to html file. when i print value it's showing values in log file

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to add variables into django templates context in its [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/). You can debug this context with [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) easily.

You might want to use [login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) and lean on django authentication system to set a login template. Another suggestion: do not use `print` for debugging, you can use the [logging module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/) or a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/chachan/f20353d38adf41b66c00) for quick lookups.

Note: Your question has a confusing code, I think you pasted some parts twice

Comment: my code is not twice. what i need is how to send python  variable value to html file?

Comment: Indentation is wrong then?. Did you check all the documentation I gave to you?, tested Django Debug Toolbar already?

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. This is the right place to discuss this problem. More people can see it later as reference

Comment: actual i am developing in window machine how to install debug toolbar in windows?

Comment: i think my problem is very simple if you see that.

Comment: To install Django Debug Toolbar `pip install django-debug-toolbar` as docs say

Comment: i installed where it will available?